# Java Applet Transparency background

Tags: java, applet, png-24

I am developing a Java applet which uses PNG-24 for icons. These icons are transparent but they simply refuse to be transparent in the app. The background always ends up white.

Is anyone familiar with this are and can give any pointers?

Thanks Mathias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page seems to give some ideas:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html

Katrien

Comment: IT WORKS! I have spent so many hours on this. Thank you so much.